# compiz high resource utilization in virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine and in that compiz process is using high CPU resource around(200 to 300). And due to this my mouse and keyboard are getting sync issue(means keyboard will not respond for few second).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I too faced same issue, so  I have switched back to GNOME Classic (Metacity) by installing the following package:

- for Ubuntu 14.04:

  ```
  apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
  ```
- for Ubuntu 16.04:

  ```
  apt-get install gnome-flashback
  ```

Then there is no trace of `compiz` in the process list...

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: try this,apt-get install gnome-session-flashback

Answer (score 0):

Compiz uses intensively a 3D accelerator. If you run your ubuntu in a virtual machine, it tries to use an emulated one.

3D accelerator emulation is mostly highly problematic in most virtualisation solutions. But sometimes it works, or it can be hacked to working, mainly in VMWare products.

Not having the hardware 3d accelerator, the 3D rendering switches to a software more. It is slow and eats a terrible mass of CPU time, this is what you are confronting.

Your possibilities:

1. You can switch to a window manager in the virtual machine, which doesn't need so many 3d thing. So you lose the beautifulness of the compiz.
2. You can switch to a different virtualization software, what can emulate 3d acceleration. However, you won't ever reach the speed of your host system with it.
3. You could utilize an alternate video card and give [direct PCI path access](https://www.google.de/search?q=pci%20direct%20path) to it to your VM. Note, it has the side effect that the crash of your VM can crash also your host machine.

I had my most luck with (1), then with (3).